# Extending jQuery Validate password functionality

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using this plugin: jQuery Validate

I have a basic form like this:

HTML

```
<form class="cmxform" id="signupForm" method="get" action="">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Validating a complete form</legend>

            <label for="firstname">Firstname</label>
            <input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text" />

            <label for="lastname">Lastname</label>
            <input id="lastname" name="lastname" type="text" />

            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input id="username" name="username" type="text" />

            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input id="password" name="password" type="password" />

            <label for="confirm_password">Confirm password</label>
            <input id="confirm_password" name="confirm_password" type="password" />

            <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

jQuery

```
$().ready(function() {

    // validate signup form on keyup and submit
    $("#signupForm").validate({
        rules: {
            firstname: "required",
            lastname: "required",
            username: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            confirm_password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5,
                equalTo: "#password"
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            firstname: "Please enter your firstname",
            lastname: "Please enter your lastname",
            username: {
                required: "Please enter a username",
                minlength: "Your username must consist of at least 2 characters"
            },
            password: {
                required: "Please provide a password",
                minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
            },
            confirm_password: {
                required: "Please provide a password",
                minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long",
                equalTo: "Please enter the same password as above"
            },
            email: "Please enter a valid email address"
        }
    });

});
```

I want to make the password need a capital letter and contain at least one number.

How would I change the rules just for password and add this in?

Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/dwhitmarsh/xXUWB/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to add your own validation method first, before the validation occurs. Personally, I recommend the document's `ready` event.
You can use the following "scaffold":

```
$(function() {
    $.validator.addMethod('capitalLetterMandatory', function(function(value, element) {
        // Return true if the validation succeeded, false otherwise.
        // Best achieved through an appropriate regular expression
    });
});
```

Then, don't forget to actually hook that rule up to your field, in your rules definition block when initializing the validator:

```
rules: {
    password: { // Note that in this line it's the field name, not the rule name, which can be confusing
         capitalLetterMandatory: true,  // rule name
         mandatory: true
    },
    // Other rules go here
}
```